# Specify all the bases for which can be explicitly constructed out of the above vectors

Tags: linear-algebra

$$v_1= 
\begin{bmatrix}                         
  1 \\
 -2 \\
 1  \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$v_2= 
\begin{bmatrix}                         
  2 \\
 -1 \\
 13  \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$v_3= 
\begin{bmatrix}                         
  7 \\
 -9 \\
 -8  \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$v_4= 
\begin{bmatrix}                         
  -4 \\
 8 \\
 -4  \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$
$$v_5= 
\begin{bmatrix}                         
  -6 \\
 7 \\
 9  \\
 \end{bmatrix}$$

(a)  Specify all the bases for which can be explicitly constructed out of the above vectors (just the unique sets, regardless of the order of vectors in each set).

I would really appreciate any help and feedback, thanks in advance!

I am confused that in this question that what is  required to do
is it using all vectors as a basis of a set V? or using such as v1 and v2 as a basis of a set V?

Comment: Specify all the bases for *what* which can be .. It is really important to know what the *what* is. If it is for "any vector space" then each single vector is a basis for a 1-d space, but if it is for $\mathbb{R}^3$ you would need three for each basis.

Comment: I'm reasonably confident that they mean for you to find all bases of $\mathbb{R^3}$.

Answer (score 1):

If the question is to find all bases of $\mathbb{R}^3$, you need to find all subsets of 3 vectors that are linearly independent. The naive way to do this is to check all $\binom{5}{3} = 10$ different subsets and test linear dependence for all of them. However, $v_4 = -4v_1$, which means that any basis you get using $v_4$ is identical to a basis you get using $v_1$. This means you only have to check 4 different sets -- that's $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ and $\{v_1, v_2, v_5\}$ and $\{v_1, v_3, v_5\}$ and $\{v_2, v_3, v_5\}$.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you want to get a basis for the whole vector space (which I will assume is $\Bbb{R}3$) or if you want to get a basis for some subspace $V$, you should think as follows.

Suppose that you have a space $V$. First, look at the dimension of the space (let’s say $n$). That will be the number of elements that you will need to form a linearly independent set that will generate a basis for that space (by the Steinitz exchange lemma).